# Firestore get path of already queried document

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get the path of a queried document in Firebase Firestore. This is my code:

```
const location = await db.doc('/locations/US/regions/IOWA').get()
console.log(location.path)
```

However `location.path` returns undefined.

`location.id` works and returns the id.

I have used this as a resource: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#path

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you call `get()` on a `DocumentReference`, you get back a [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot), which does not have a `path` property.

You're probably looking for `location.ref.path`.

Answer (score 4):

The currently accepted answer appears to be outdated, as a`DocumentSnapshot` does now store the path.

Every `DocumentSnapshot` has a `DocumentReference` found under the `ref` property (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#ref)

In the `DocumentSnapshot`, you can then find a string representation of the path under the `path` property` (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#path)

In short, you can simply use `doc.ref.path` to get the path.

Answer (score 1):

The API documentation for DocumentSnapshot says that the reference of the document can be found in its reference property. So you will want to use this: doc.reference.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is old and answered question,  this is how I get the document reference from queried document

```
d.get()
.then(td=>{
   let taskDep = td.data()
   taskDep.id = td.id
   taskDep.ref = td.ref

})
```